# What is the best practice when subscribing components to a service's observable? [Angular 2+]

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-services, angular-components, angular-observable

I'm building an application that grabs video data from YouTube.

There are so many resources for different solutions but is there a method that is considered best practice when subscribing components to a service?

This is so far what I have:

```
// Component
export class LandingYoutubeComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private youtube: YoutubeService) { 
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.youtube.getVideos().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      }
    }

// Service
export class YoutubeService {

  videoSubscription: Observable<any>;
  API_KEY: string = 'someKey';
  CHANNEL_ID: string = 'someID';
  configUrl: string = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${this.CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&key=${this.API_KEY}`

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.videoSubscription = this.http.get(this.configUrl);  //  create observable for external subscriptions
  }

  getVideos() {
    return this.videoSubscription;
  }
}
```

Both the component and service are abstracted from each other and have pasted the logic encapsulated by each class.

From what I know from JS is that arrays and and objects are passed by reference which is technically what I'm doing here but is that the right decision?

I just want to know if that is considered best practice to do and if it isn't, how should I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing worth to mention is that ``this.http.get(this.configUrl)`` isn't a ``Subscription`` because it returns an ``Observable``. To get actual subscription you neet to point on ``this.http.get(this.configUrl).subscribe()`` - so the moment when you watching on changes or in your example making request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consume API via http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683626/consume-api-via-http)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't keep the `Observable` as a property of the service; this has less to do with reference types like you've mentioned and more with the design of `Observable`s in general.

What you're doing isn't necessarily bad; however, An `Observable` is a contract that is only run when subscribed to. The `Observable` returned by the `http.get` is what's being assigned to your service as a property; if it was never subscribed to, no http calls are made...but if three components subscribe to that `Observable`, three separate http calls would be made.

The `Observable` returned from the `HttpClient` is a cold, finite observable. This means it will emit one single value and then send an `unsubscribe` signal. If a component knows this and wants the data only once, why not just return the `Observable` created from `http.get` directly? That way the caller can use any amount of `Observable` operators on the `Observable` without affecting any other components trying to get the same value.

Having `Observables` as a property of Services (instead of just returning new ones in methods) **does** make sense for some things, but instead of `Observables` they're usually `Subjects`. That's the whole design philosophy behind ngrx-store's state management. But for cold, finite `Observables`, just return the `Observable` to the caller.

Comment: I don't understand, how is there 3 separate http requests when we make the http request once in the constructor and then return the same instance of the observable to 3 different components? Unless we are creating 3 different instances of the service.

Comment: That's how `Observables` work. They accept an `Observer` and a method to run and return a value to emit. When they are subscribed to, that method is invoked. The `Observable` itself doesn't have the return value of the http call, it's more like a pipe for where to direct the result.

Comment: You can try it yourself in your browser; create one `Observable` from `http.get` and subscribe to it multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

This was the solution I ended up with:

```
// Component
export class LandingYoutubeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  videos: any[];

  constructor(private youtube: YoutubeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //  change videos array for every change in service.
    this.youtube.getVideoSubject().subscribe(([v1, v2, v3, v4]: any[]) => {
      this.videos = v1 && v2 && v3 && v4 ? [v1, v2, v3, v4] : [];
      console.log(this.videos);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.youtube.getVideoSubject().unsubscribe();
  }
}

// Service
export class YoutubeService {

  private videos: any[];
  private videoSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  private API_KEY: string = 'someKey';
  private CHANNEL_ID: string = 'someId';
  private configUrl: string = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${this.CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&key=${this.API_KEY}`

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.videos = [];
    this.videoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(this.videos);
    this.http.get(this.configUrl).subscribe((videos: any) => {
      this.videos = videos.items;
      this.videoSubject.next(this.videos.slice());  //  emit videos for all subscriptions
    });
  }

  getVideoSubject(): BehaviorSubject<any[]> {
    return this.videoSubject; //  return reference to BehaviorSubject
  }
}
```

As `@joh04667` mentioned, the previous solution built a new http request for every subscription made to the initial solution's service. So, to reduce http requests made I wanted to populate a service property by creating only one request despite multiple subscriptions. I have also changed the `Observable` to an inherited class `BehaviorSubject`.

So now, components which would like to subscribe to the service now subscribe to changes inside the service's property instead of building a new request for every new subscription.